# In Linux (Fedora 25), why am I getting a warning about DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID not being set?

Tags: linux, fedora

Here is an example.

```
$ gnome-terminal &
[1] 8521
$ Warning: DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID not set and no fallback available.
```

I don't get this warning if I start a new terminal using "Open Terminal" in the File menu of another terminal.  This behavior started immediately after I upgraded from Fedora 23 to 25.

Comment: Are you running this _from_ gnome-terminal? Are you running under GNOME?

Comment: @mattdm  yes to both questions

Comment: Interesting; I can't reproduce. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: I have the same thing

Comment: I have the same problem, any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same thing with a Fedora 27 install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with fedora 27 and the solution was change the settings in the user session to initiate with the GNOME on Xorg (There are 3 options: GNOME, GNOME Classic and GNOME on Xorg). The first time that I changed this option was when a problem to share my screen in the Google Meet emerged.

The links bellow explains the varible DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID and the problem with share the screen.

[Desktop Entry Spec](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)

[Bug 1369218](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369218)